# What does an unfinished parentheses set mean? $\left(y\ln y - e^{-xy}\right)dx + \left( \frac{1}{y} + x\ln y\right.\,\, dy = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am currently taking a differential equations course and this homework equation popped up

> 11. $$\left(y\ln y - e^{-xy}\right)dx + \left( \frac{1}{y} + x\ln y\right.\,\, dy = 0$$

As the title suggests, I am asking for the meaning of farthest left parentheses to the right. It seems unfinished, but it probably means something. For clarification, it's the $\left(\frac{1}{y}\right.$ part. All help is appreciated and thank you in advance.

Note: I apologize if the equation turns out improperly formatted, it is my first post. Please bear with me!
[Homework pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndmZo.png)

Comment: They shouldn't mean anything and is likely a typo on the original author's part.  I have literally never seen a parenthesis by itself without its pair, and even more specifically have never seen parentheses used not as a [dyck word](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Dyck_word).

Comment: I've added a linked picture. There's too many to think its a simple typo. Thank you for your time though.

Comment: I expect it absolutely *is* just a typo or a rendering error either on the part of your reader if it is electronic, on the part of the person who generated the file (*it appears to be a screenshot of the book, not a physical copy*), or just a mistake on the author's part.  With so many occurrences, I expect it would be the first of those possibilities.

Comment: You would notice that the only times that it happens in the image is when the paired left parenthesis occupies a greater height.  That can't just be coincidence... There appears to be an error in rendering a tall right-parenthesis.  The reader can handle $(~)$ but it can't handle $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}~\\~\end{smallmatrix}\right)$

Comment: These really are typographical errors. Sometimes there isn't any choice for where the matching symbol must be, but it certainly isn't standard notation to leave that implied. My guess is that the typing was left to an underling and the result was not proofread.

Comment: I guess you learn something new everyday. I did not know that there could be such things as rendering errors with generating symbols. Just to double check, I will see if any of my classmates has a hardcopy. In the meantime, I will take your advice. Thank you for your time and have a great weekend!

Answer (score 4):

This is just a typo and should read

$$(y \,\mathrm{ln}\,y - (e^{-xy}))dx + \bigg( \frac{1}{y} + x \,\mathrm{ln}\,y \bigg)dy = 0$$

Comment: Matching is corrected, but sizing could be improved :/

Answer (score 4):

To second the other answer: indeed, there is no conventional (2017) usage in mathematics in which a "right/close parenthesis" is omitted. It is some sort of miscopy/typo/mis-software-scan/read.

Sure, in some alternative universe, or in the future, there might be some useful/cute convention about missing right-closing marks, but in all the mathematics I'm aware of in this year, this is just a mistake/typo/mis-copy/software-scan-error...